# What iterative method can effectively solve a linear system with this kind of spectrum

Tags: linear-algebra, iterative-method, preconditioning

I have a linear system with matrix which eigenvalues are uniformly distributed on the unit circle like this:

[image]

Is it possible to solve this kind of system effectively by iterative method, maybe with some preconditioner?

Comment: I think MINRES will do this, although I only know of a similar results for a real spectrum. Do you know more about the matrix (in particular, is it normal)?

Comment: Also, take a look at http://page.math.tu-berlin.de/~liesen/Publicat/LiTiGAMM.pdf

Comment: [This paper](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/publication/PDF/1992_52.pdf) is also a good reference. In particular, applying the conjugate gradient method to the normal equations ($A^*Ax = A^*b$), while inadvisable for matrices with large condition number, might work in your case because the singular values look pretty close to 1.

Comment: @ChristianClason in general case the matrix is not normal. It has a certain block structure and is sparse. Thank you for the reference!

Comment: @DanielShapero the paper is awesome, thank you!

Comment: If the matrix is highly non-normal then my suggestion of CGNE is wrong, but that paper ought to be a good start. The library [PETSc](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/) has pretty much every Krylov subspace solver under the sun, so you can try them all and see which one works best. There's also a Python interface for it, which makes things much more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix is very well-conditioned, hence GMRES(k) should work fine without preconditioner.

Comment: Although the matrix is well-conditioned, this does not necessarily imply that GMRES converges well. Octave (Matlab) example: ` n=100;A=eye(n);p=[n, 1:n-1];A=A(:,p);condition_number=cond(A),b=eye(n,1)+rand(n,1)*1e-6;[x, flag, relres, iter, resvec] = gmres (A,b);close all;semilogy(resvec);figure;plot(eig(A),"."); `

Comment: @wim: You are right; I was assuming without good reason that $A$ was normal.